# ¿Cómo hago dos ng-repeat en un mismo elemento?

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Esto es lo que tengo, selecciono una categoría para que me muestre en los encabezados de la tabla las actividades que estén registradas en una circular de una categoria específica.

```
<button class="btn " ng-class="{'btn-warning':categoria.id === option, 'btn-default':categoria.id != option}" ng-repeat="categoria in categorias" name="option" ng-click="changeOption(categoria)" >@{{categoria.nombre }}</button>

<table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover" >
 <thead>
 <th>Nº</th>
 <th>Nombre de club</th>
 <th ng-repeat="circular in circulares | filter:{ categoria_id: option}">
   <th ng-repeat="actividad in circular.actividades">@{{actividad.nombre}</th>
 </th>
 <th>Acciones</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 </tbody>
```

Comment: que es lo que falla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se pueden anidar perfectamente los ng-repeat. 
Tu problema es que estas intentando anidar tag `<th></th>` y esto provoca que el primer  se cierre con el primer  y te falla.

Mira este ejemplo... aunque tendrás que adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover" >
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Nº</th>
       <th>Nombre de club</th>
       <th ng-repeat="circular in circulares" >
         <span ng-repeat="actividad in circular.actividades">
            {{actividad.nombre}}
         </span>
       </th>
       <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
```

Controller:

```
angularApp = angular.module('miApp', []);
angularApp.controller('miController', function($scope){
  $scope.circulares = [{
    categoria_id: 1,
    actividades : [{id:1, nombre: 'aaa'},{id:2, nombre: 'bbb'}]
  },
                      {
    categoria_id: 2,
    actividades : [{id:1, nombre: 'ccc'},{id:2, nombre: 'ddd'}]
  },
                      {
    categoria_id: 3,
    actividades : [{id:1, nombre: 'eee'},{id:2, nombre: 'fff'}]
  }]
})
```

Comment: no me funciona :( y es que categoría es otro arreglo adentro de circulares

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de como es tu json?

Comment: en mi controlador lo tengo asi: $scope.categorias = Categoria.query();
                                                 $scope.circulares = Circular.query();
                                                 $scope.actividades = Actividad.query();

Comment: lo que quiero mostras son las actividades en el encabezado de la tabla.. pero las actividades se tienen que mostrar segun la categoria, pero actividades no tiene categoria sino circular y las actividades son de una circular